# Separating Divs

Tags: html, css, css-position, margin, padding

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

[image: Image 3]
I am trying to separate this 2 divs with a space between them (Please see Picture 1).
The problem is when I add margin or padding this happens (Please see Picture 2).

Here is my code, Please take note I am not using Bootstrap:

```css
.row {
  margin-left: -0.75rem !important;
  margin-right: -0.75rem !important;
}

.col-50 {
  width: 50%;
  float: left;
  position: relative;
  min-height: 1px;
  margin-left: 0.75rem !important;
  margin-right: 0.75rem !important;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-50">
    <div class="card-box">
      <h4 class="header-title">View Data</h4>
      <div class="table-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-50">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <a class="btn-excel" href="#"><span>Excel</span></a>
              <a class="btn-pdf" href="#"><span>PDF</span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-50">
            <form class="pull-right">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
              <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-100">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-50">
    <div class="card-box">
      <h4 class="header-title">View Data</h4>
      <div class="table-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-50">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <a class="btn-excel" href="#"><span>Excel</span></a>
              <a class="btn-pdf" href="#"><span>PDF</span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-50">
            <form class="pull-right">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
              <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-100">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my HTML and CSS code. I am trying to make this work for days. Please help. I want to separate these 2 divs with equal space between them perfectly. I am trying to mimic the grid from Bootstrap in order to learn before I try the Bootstrap approach.

Answer (score 1):

I would use `flexbox` to achieve the same results. Or if you aim only to modern browsers, use the newest `grid` properties.

```css
.row {
  background-color: red;
  display: flex;
  flex: 2 0 50% 50%;
  width: 100%;
}

.card-box {
  width: 100%;
}

.col-50 {
  background-color: yellow;
  display: flex;
  flex: 2 0 50% 50%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-50">
    <div class="card-box">
      <h4 class="header-title">View Data</h4>
      <div class="table-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-50">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <a class="btn-excel" href="#"><span>Excel</span></a>
              <a class="btn-pdf" href="#"><span>PDF</span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-50">
            <form class="pull-right">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
              <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-100" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-50">
    <div class="card-box">
      <h4 class="header-title">View Data</h4>
      <div class="table-container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-50">
            <div class="btn-group">
              <a class="btn-excel" href="#"><span>Excel</span></a>
              <a class="btn-pdf" href="#"><span>PDF</span></a>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="col-50">
            <form class="pull-right">
              <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control">
              <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-100" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried adding margin-right / left to the .cardbox div?

**EDIT:**

You have to extend the width on row/container, the div you have around the whole page.

Comment: I works but the problem now is  the edges now not stretched

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Please see image 3.

Comment: remove width=50% in col-50, then try adding a custom width and height to cardbox

Comment: I did that but still doing image 3.I need to separate the 2 divs in the middle but the left of div 1 and right of div 2 is stretch align with the text

Answer (score 0):

add `*{ box-sizing: border-box; }` in your,  remove negative margin for `row` and use padding instead of margin for `.col-50`

```css
.col-50 {
width: calc(50% - 1.5rem);
float: left;
position: relative;
min-height: 1px;
padding-left: 0.75rem !important;
padding-right: 0.75rem !important;
margin:0 0.75rem;
background:green
}


.row {
margin-left: -0.75rem !important;
margin-right: -0.75rem !important;}

*{
  box-sizing: border-box; 
}
input{
  width:100%
}
/*.col-50:first-child{
  margin-left:0
}
.col-50:last-child{
  margin-right:0
}*/
```

```html
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-50">
        <div class="card-box">
            <h4 class="header-title">View Data</h4>
            <div class="table-container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-50">
                        <div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn-excel" href="#"><span>Excel</span></a> <a class="btn-pdf" href="#"><span>PDF</span></a> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-50">
                        <form class="pull-right">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control"> <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span> </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-100"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-50">
        <div class="card-box">
            <h4 class="header-title">View Data</h4>
            <div class="table-container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-50">
                        <div class="btn-group"> <a class="btn-excel" href="#"><span>Excel</span></a> <a class="btn-pdf" href="#"><span>PDF</span></a> </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-50">
                        <form class="pull-right">
                            <input type="text" placeholder="Search..." class="form-control"> <span><i class="fa fa-search"></i></span> </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-100"> </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: it still doing the image 2

Comment: did you removed negative margin for row and used padding instead of margin for .col-50 and also added box-sizing: border-box;  to your code?

Comment: yes it does the image 3 please see i need to separate the 2 divs in the middle and the left of div 1 and right of div 2 is stretch align with the text

Comment: now i just need to get rid of the padding-left of DIV 1 and padding-right of DIV 2 in order to separate the equally